# Editing values in dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains dictionaries called `tick_list`, as such:

```
(1, {'Wins: ': 0, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(2, {'Wins: ': 0, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(3, {'Wins: ': 0, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(4, {'Wins: ': 0, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(5, {'Wins: ': 0, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
```

Let's say I want to add 1 to dictionary 5's `Wins:`. I tried:

```
tick_list[5]["Wins: "] += 1
```

But this resulted in:

```
(1, {'Wins: ': 1, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(2, {'Wins: ': 1, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(3, {'Wins: ': 1, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(4, {'Wins: ': 1, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
(5, {'Wins: ': 1, 'WinRate: ': 0, 'Total: ': 0})
```

Any explanations as to why that's happening? Any how do I get to to add 1 to only 5's dictionary?

Disregard the brackets `()` instead of `{}`, I used a for loop to print the dictionary.

Comment: Are they *same dict* ? I mean you just did something like: `d = {};  a = d; a['test'] = 1; print(d)`   <--- run and check the output.

Comment: How do you create the tick list? Try to use a shallow copy!

Comment: @fodma1 THANK YOU! , I figured it out! See, I created the inner dictionary using a variable set to it, then iterating to copy that variable into my outer dictionary. This resulted in the inner dictionary being the same variable, so one change changed them all!